# Angular power spectrum: Calculating bias from N weighted events

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, spherical-harmonics

I'm interested in calculating the angular power spectrum $C_{l,N,\omega}$ of $N$ weighted (weight $\omega_i$ for event $i$) events from a full sky map with distribution $C_l$?
Interesting quantities would be:

- The mean of $C_{l,N,\omega}$: $\langle C_{l,N,\omega}\rangle$
- The variance of $C_{l,N,\omega}$: $\mathrm{Var}(C_{l,N,\omega})$

Why I ask this question: In reality we observe only a certain number N of events of the true sky-distribution and this leads to a bias of the $C_l$ s.
When we have energy dependent detector effects, it is important to weight each event $i$ by the observed Energy $\omega_i(E)$.

For simplification we could start with the special case of a pure isotropic sky map. If we neglect the weights, we know from Poisson noise (we observe $N$ events at random positions):
    $$\left<C_{l,N}\right>=\frac{4\pi}{N}$$
    $$\mathrm{Var}(C_{l,N})= \frac{2}{2l+1} \left(\frac{4\pi}{N}\right)^2$$

The expression above I have checked in a Monte Carlo experiment.

It would be great, if anybody could tell me, how this expression changes, if we weight each event i by the observed Energy $\omega_i(E)$?